# How to see if a checkbox is checked on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I started a project on a gui to me any my friends but I can't figure out how to read a boolean from another form. This is that part of my code. Im really new to coding so I would really suggest (the one thats reading this) to ask a question what I should explain more. This code doesnt work but I have no idea why. Im doing a new settings called s and then I try to read a boolean from settings but it doesnt work.

```
// main form
 private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings s = new Settings();          
        {
            if(s.checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                Opacity = 0.9; //For an example

            }              
        }


// Settings form
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don;'t know what you want to do

Comment: "new" means it's new, so you are not referencing the "existing" form you already have on the screen.

Comment: In your sample code, you are never showing the `s` form. Is that intentional? But, to get the value of a control on another form, you could make the declaration of the control `public`, so another form can read it directly, or you can make a public read-only property that reflects the value of the control in the second form.

Comment: public System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;

Comment: Also, for readabilily, consider giving your controls meaningful names, rather than `checkBox2` and `checkBox5`...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a public read-only property that reflects the value of the  checkbox on the `Settings` form:

```
public partial class Settings : Form
{
    // This is a read-only property providing access to the Checked propery of a checkbox
    public bool CheckBoxIsChecked => checkBox2.Checked;

    // Rest of form code omitted...
}
```

Then, when you instantiate the `Settings` form from your `Main` form, you can access the property.

It's not clear from your example when you want to display the `Settings` form, but here's an example where it's shown modally (the user has to close it to get back to the `Main` form), and the value of the checkbox is captured:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.ShowDialog();

        // Here we can get the checked state of the checkbox on the Settings form
        if (settings.CheckBoxIsChecked)
        {
            Opacity = 0.9;
        }
    }

    // Rest of form code omitted...
}
```